# Generic Formula for $\prod\limits_{i}(x+k_i)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm asking if there is a way to generalize or develop the product of a finite number of linear polynomials like $(x+k)$.

I know that
$$(x+a)(x+b)=x^2+x(a+b)+ab=x^2+x\sum\limits_{i\in a,b}i+\prod\limits_{i\in a,b}i$$

Computing $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$ we obtain
$$(x^2+x(a+b)+ab)(x+c)=x^3+x^2(a+b+c)+x(ab+c(a+b))+abc$$

But if I want to compute it over $i\in M=\{a,b,c,d...n\}$? Is there a simplified formula with sums and products directly over the set of $M$? Or do I have to compute every single products? Moreover if I change the sign of the constant? 
$$(x-a)(x-b)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-n)$$
Can we develop a generic formula also in this case?

P.S. Obviously every element in $M$ have multiplicity equal to 1.

Comment: This is a direct application of the binomial theorem.

Comment: Binomial theorem is the wrong tool here. Look up Vieta's formulas.

Comment: What wrongs with $\prod(x+k_i)$? Seems generic enough for me!

Comment: I want to write it in the $x^n+x^{n-1}...$ form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) are what you are looking for. For example,
if we have a set $\, M =\{a,b,c\}, \,$ then 
$$ e_1(M) = a+b+c, \quad e_2(M) = ab+ac+bc, \quad e_3(M) = abc. $$

For your question about changing signs, each symmetric polynomial is homogeneous and thus changing sign results in a factor of $\,(-1)^d\,$ where $\, d \,$ is the degree of the polynomial.

By the way, the elementary symmetric polynomials also work with [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). The elements of $\,M\,$ can have multiplicities greater than $1$. For example if
 $\, M =\{a,a,a\}, \,$ then 
 $\, e_1(M) = 3a, \,$ $ e_2(M) = 3a^2, \,$ $ e_3(M) = a^3.\, $ This gives us
 $\, (x+a)(x+a)(x+a) = x^3 + 3ax^2 + 3a^2x + a^3. \,$

Comment: It seems this is the correct answer man. Thanks, I'll try this.